# How do I ask my friend to recommend me a manga?

Tags: particle-を

I know manga is 漫画 and recommend is 勧める.

Do I just... 漫画を進める？

Answer (score 1):

I would probably say:

> お勧めの漫画はある?

Or:

> 一番お勧めの漫画は何ですか。

Or:

> あなたのお勧めの漫画を教えてください。

Just saying `漫画をお勧め` (closest to your translation) sounds too harsh, like you are giving a command.

Comment: The first sentence is probably the most common. Or, as Japanese tends to rely a lot on context, if you speak to your friend about manga (so the context is set), you can just say :
「お勧めは何だ？」

Comment: ^ 「お勧めは**何だ？** 」はやめときなはれ・・　せめて「お勧めは何？」くらいで・・

Comment: 「お勧めは何？」って女らしいじゃないですか？少なくとも、そう言われました。

Comment: 「～～なに？」って語尾、別に女っぽくないですけど・・・「～～どこ？」「～～だれ？」とかとおんなじで。。